# OOP MVC structure binding thru interface

Tags: oop, go

I'm trying to build an MVC framework with OOP style.
My idea was to bind controller & service during route session and let function accessible thru interface.

I've encounter an issue when function triggered to service level, it keep returning
"runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

Route:

```
var (
    testService     service.Person             = service.NewPerson()
    testController  controller.TestController  = controller.NewTestController(testService)
)

func RouteHandler(rg *gin.RouterGroup) {
    routes := rg.Group("/api")
    {
        routes .GET("/test", testController.Greet)
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
type TestController interface {
    Greet(ctx *gin.Context)
}

type testController struct {
    testService service.Person
}

func NewTestController(testService service.Person) TestController {
    return &testController{
        testService: testService,
    }
}

func (controller *testController) Greet(ctx *gin.Context) {
    res := controller.testService.Greet()
    fmt.Println(res)
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, "test")
}
```

Service:

```
type Person interface {
    Greet() string
}

type person struct {
    Person
}

func NewPerson() Person {
    return &person{}
}

func Greet() string {
    return "Hello"
}
```

Comment: Go is not classically object oriented, so most attempts to write OOP in Go fail.

Comment: As for your specific error, there's not enough information here to debug. Please update your question with full details. And start by looking at the stack trace. It tells you exactly which line of your code caused the error. Maybe that will be enough for you to solve on your own. If not, we'll need that information (and the corresponding code) to help debug.

Answer (score 1):

Currently `person` service embeds the `Person`, but `NewPerson` factory method does not assign anything to the `Person` field, leaving it as nil. When `Greet` method is invoked on a `person` struct, the call is delegated to embedded interface `Person` which is nil and this causes a crash.

Assuming that the `person` is an "implementation" of the `Person` interface or more precisely the `person` should provide the methods with the same signature that is defined by the `Person` interface, the fix could be as follow:

```
type Person interface {
    Greet() string
}

type person struct {
}

func NewPerson() Person {
    return &person{}
}

func (person) Greet() string {
    return "Hello"
}
```

It is worth mentioning that interfaces in Go are implicit. It is possible that your current `person` declaration is due to habits from other languages, where you have to explicitly indicate that a class (in Go there are no classes) implements some interface.